# spark's example can not build in intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I follow someone's tutorial to compile spark 2.1.0 and run one of its example in intellij IDEA 2016.3.4(scala 2.11.8) ,here is my steps:

1. download spark 2.1.0 from git(win 10 64bit)
2. I build it using "$ build/mvn -T 4 -DskipTests clean package" in cygwin
3. open the project in intellij
4. mark spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.11's target directory as  Sources,and also its sub directory \target\scala-2.11\src_managed\main\compiled_avro\org\apache\spark\streaming\flume\sink
5. add  {spark dir}/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars/*.jars as spark-examples_2.11 's  Dependencies

But when I build the spark project,here is error message:
[image]

Even I delete this test class SparkSinkSuite ,the similar error "object xx is not a member of package xx" happen in other class(I found all the problem class are in 'external' module)
I've tried restart the intellij even the computer ,it doesn't help.